# Upload image to Eventbrite with Zapier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier, eventbrite

I am trying to upload an image to Eventbrite to serve as an event's logo. Zapier allows for custom code (python or javascript+node.js) but does not allow for external libraries to be used or imported.

In the Custom Code step I use javascript+node.js to make the api call. All works well except for the uploading of the image file. Whether I use the image url or a file from google drive, I get:

status_code
400
error_description
The file did not upload properly or is not a valid image.
error
BAD_FILE

Here is the code being used along with the inputData:

````
    image: 'https://coachieve.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/nyc-skyline.jpg',
  };
  let uploadToken = await fetch(
    `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/media/upload/?type=image-event-logo&token=abc123`
  ).then((res) => res.json());

 // console.log('uploadToken', uploadToken);

  const {upload_data} = uploadToken;
  let imageUploadedRes = await fetch(uploadToken.upload_url, {
    method: uploadToken.upload_method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', //'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
  upload_data:{
      AWSAccessKeyId: upload_data.AWSAccessKeyId,
      bucket: upload_data.bucket,
      acl: upload_data.acl,
      key: upload_data.key,
      signature: upload_data.signature,
    policy: upload_data.policy,
    [uploadToken.file_parameter_name]: inputData.image,
    }
    }),
  });//.then((res) => res.json());
  console.log('imageUploadedRes', imageUploadedRes);

  let image = await fetch(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/media/upload/`, {
    method: uploadToken.upload_method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer xyz789',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      upload_token: uploadToken.upload_token,
    }),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  console.log('image', image);```

IS there a way to get images from a link or perhaps stored in a google drive to upload to eventbrite via zapier? 

Eventbrite uploads media in 3 steps (get an upload token, upload the image, retrieve the image
````